# how to get managed bean property value inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Can anyone tell me how to get the managed bean property value inside the javascript method

something like

```
function fonction1() {
  var variable = "#{myBean.property}";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code posted so far? It should work just fine, provided that it's enclosed in a Facelets file and the property returns a valid (escaped) JS string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can like this:

```
<h:inputText id="propertyId" value="#{myBean.property}" style="display:none"/>
```

and access it like this (note that if its inside a form you might need to add the form prefix)

```
alert($('#propertyId').val()); // or alert($('#myFormId\\:propertyId').val());
```

Comment: can i  make a hidden button and create and launch a click on the button from JavaScript ?

Comment: yep , `<h:commandButton id="my_button" style="display:none"/>` , then click it like this `$("#my_button").click()`;

Comment: function fnc(){         length=document.getElementById('form:aa').value.length;
    if(length == 10){
     $("#hh").click();
      }}

When I execute this function  click launches when the page loads but not when I call the function :(

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but is looks like a different question, so accept the answer and ask a new question...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it to be updated to the current value inside the bean. You can't! You can only add it to javascript during load time. If you want it to be updated you will have to do ajax calls to fetch the current value.

Comment: can you give me an exemple