# Use js function calls the background method in the JSF, and obtain the return value of the background bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, background

I have to use HTML component in the JSF page, such as drop-down components.I want to achieve this goal: when I click on the drop-down, the selected value will be passed to the method of a background bean, then receives results of this method processing , and can receive value passed to the other js function.

Comment: Why do you have to use a plain HTML `<select><option>...</option>...</select>` instead of using the standard JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>` which renders a corresponding HTML `<select><option>...</option>...</select>` in turn? I would be better for someone else to understand the question thoroughly, if you demonstrated the phenomenon with a shortest possible example - in favour of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to do a queryBuilder module in my web project, JSF components are not a good way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Why are they not good components to achieve this goal?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I need to use has the very good flexibility and operability of the component, if use primefaces components, it will become very complex, but use HTML tags/component, is not very complicated.

Comment: I have no clue what you actually mean by your last statement.

Comment: Please see the following answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's not trivial and you will lost a beauty of JSF but it's possible. I will give you direction how you can achieve these by using a [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) libary and `<p:remoteCommand>` component:

To call JSF bean method from javascript you can use Primefaces's `<p:remoteCommand/>`, for example:

```
<script>
   function processResult(){
       //...grab result from hidden-result field by JavaScript or jQuery
   }


    function makeSelection(){
    //...code to get selected value via javascript or jQuery

       processSelection([{name:'selected', value:'<selected value>'}]);
    }
</script>
<p:remoteCommand name="processSelection" action="#{bean.processSelected}" update="hidden-result" oncomplete="processResult();" />



 <h:outputText id="hidden-result" value="#{bean.result}" style="display:none;"/>
```

You call JavaScript function `makeSelection` which take selected value and pass it to the bean. Then it updates field with `id='hidden-result'` and when completed it will call function `processResult` where you should grab value from this field' by JavaScript or by jQuery use it whatever you want.

To receive these parameters in a backing bean you should use the following code:

```
public void processSelected() {
    String selectedValue = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param");  
   //... make whatever you want with the selected value
   result = "Result from process by JSON or plain text";
}
```

At the beginning you get the passed parameter, then make your process and apply result to `result` value parameter which connected to `<h:outputText/>`

**Please pay attention that I didn't check this code and it might contain a typo**

Also I recommend you to take a look at this questions:

1. [Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript)
2. [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-jsf-components-using-jquery)
3. [how to get managed bean property value inside javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812163/how-to-get-managed-bean-property-value-inside-javascript)

Comment: It mainly works, a small review is to get a hidden span with display:none instead of display:hidden:

<h:outputText id="hidden-result" value="#{bean.result}" style="display:hidden;"/>